# force windows into successful sleep mode

Tags: sleep

some applications can prevent windows from going into sleep mode(e.g: connectify hotspot), in these cases, the monitor (laptop's screen) turns off and windows try to go into the sleep mode but because these kinds of application won't allow windows to do so, it stays at this state **(screen is off while system is still running and there's hard disk activity)** and you no longer have control over your system to bring it back;

the only solution now is to cut off power;

as you know windows has forceful shutdown/restart; in this case windows bypasses applications preventions and successfully does restart/shutdown;

1. what about forceful sleep?
2. is there any way to know which applications are preventing windows from going into successful sleep mode?

OS: Windows 7 Ultimate x64

Comment: Can you give instructions on how to cause sleeping to fail?  Can you name a pre-loaded or at least free application that prevents Windows from properly sleeping, so people can re-create the problem?

Comment: connectify hotspot v4.3

Comment: I don't want to add this as an answer unless it works for you (since I don't have that program installed), but have you tried hitting `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`Del` and selecting sleep from the drop-down menu of the power icon on the splash screen with the green arrow options "Switch User", "Log Off", "Start Task Manager", etc.?  ("Sleep" via tiny arrow beside red power icon near lower right corner)

Comment: screen is off; how can I do that?!
besides, I tried every sleep function without success;

Comment: I am trying to answer how to get your computer to sleep properly, once you know you are running a program that might interrupt it (as per your title: "force windows into successful sleep mode").  What to do to *recover* from a failed sleep (or force it the *rest of the way* into sleep mode), that seems like a bit of a different question.  (Does `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`Del` have no effect at all?  How about the sleep button or power button?)  If you end up giving up on that for now and rebooting, do you mind trying what I suggested?

Comment: Check out this question (and answer), by the way, if there is any chance the sleep mode failure is *not* due to any particular program: http://superuser.com/questions/117594/windows-7-pro-x64-suffering-from-insomnia EDIT This question and it's accepted answer might be even more helpful to you: http://superuser.com/questions/175074/machine-seems-to-sleep-but-doesnt-power-off